# Not able to connect github through ssh OS X

Tags: ssh, github

I'm trying to setup github. I have generated the public key and pasted in my account. But when 
I try to do ssh -T git@github.com, I get **ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out**.

I tried **sudo route add 207.97.227.239 10.0.0.1** (ip,gateway) as mentioned in a stackoverflow solution. But nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use SSH to connect to GitHub, you can also use HTTPS for any repository.

[See this blog post for more details](https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support)

Comment: I'm unable to use git submodules as it tries to access git protocol

Comment: There is no restriction in my company, I can change firewall settings too. How do I enable ssh and push code in github. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what the firewall issue would be for you. Can you ssh to other computers inside your network on port 22? If not you will need to enable outgoing access to port 22 in your computers firewall. The Git protocol operates over port 9418 by default, so you will have to use that to access the submodules that you can't otherwise access. You could also convince the people maintaining the repository to switch to using https:// URLs for submodules.

Comment: This answer isn't useful if you're only allowed to connect via SSH, like I am in my company.

Comment: @Mark: So you seem to have a different issue. You may want to try my own tool, [`github-keygen`](https://github.com/dolmen/github-keygen), that will help you to properly define your SSH settings for Github.

Comment: @MarkRausch If they don't let you access GitHub using HTTPS you cannot browse it, so you are really stuck there!